# Data is nil from image string.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdate

It is my save method :

```
-(NSString *)saveImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSInteger RandomIndex = arc4random() % 1000;
    NSString *randomImageName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",RandomIndex];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:randomImageName];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:savedImagePath error:nil];
        NSLog(@"file removed from path");
    }
    NSLog(@"Saved Image Path : %@",savedImagePath);
    NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];

    self.teamLogo = savedImagePath;

    return savedImagePath;
}
```

I try to load image and put into control :

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.team.logo];
    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

self.team.logo is from DB. I keep string in base. In debug mode i got this string :

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7CD69EC9-9C20-48EE-B611-FC2353BC31B0/Documents/Image364.png

and myData is still nil. Do you have idea why ?

Comment: Is there a file there? Does it contain data?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded container and inside is file Image364.png and I can open it. Looks fine

Comment: `self.team.logo` is retrieved after doing a "recompile"? You talk about "DB", so my guess is that the path changed. You should only keep what's after Documents/, and rebuilt it from there again, with `NSDocumentDirectory` stuff. For example, save two image between to "recompile", and compare what's between `/Application/` and `/Documents/`, you'll understand.

Comment: I should do sth like this :
NSString *string = [[savedImagePath componentsSeparatedByString:@"Documents/"] objectAtIndex:1];
    
    self.teamLogo = string;

Just substring and take only Image364.png  or I dont understand you

Answer (score 0):

Starting from IOS 8 layout of containers changed. So don't store full path to your DB. Instead just store your image name. For recalling the image use:

```
NSString *temp = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image364.png"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:temp];
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:myData];
```

I hope it helps.